# What is the significance of the number 93 in Unicode?

Tags: javascript, unicode, bit-manipulation

Since there is currently no universal way to read live data from an audio track in JavaScript I'm using a small [library/API](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2011/03/music-visualizer-in-html5-js-with-source-code.html) to read volume data from a text file that I converted from an MP3 offline.

The string looks like this

> ```
> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!###"~{~||ysvgfiw`gXg}i}|mbnTaac[Wb~v|xqsfSeYiV`R
> ][\Z^RdZ\XX`Ihb\O`3Z1W*I'D'H&J&J'O&M&O%O&I&M&S&R&R%U&W&T&V&m%\%n%[%Y%I&O'P'G
> 'L(V'X&I'F(O&a&h'[&W'P&C'](I&R&Y'\)\'Y'G(O'X'b'f&N&S&U'N&P&J'N)O'R)K'T(f|`|d
> //etc...
> ```

and the idea is basically that at a given point in the song the Unicode number of the character at the corresponding point in the text file yields a nominal value to represent volume.

The library translates the data (in this case, a stereo track) with the following (simplified here):

> ```
> getVolume = function(sampleIndex,o) {
>     o.left = Math.min(1,(this.data.charCodeAt(sampleIndex*2|0)-33)/93);
>     o.right = Math.min(1,(this.data.charCodeAt(sampleIndex*2+1|0)-33)/93);
>     }
> ```

I'd like some insight into how the file was encoded in the first place, and how I'm making use of it here.

What is the significance of `93` and `33`?

What is the purpose of the bitwise `|`?

Is this a common means of porting information (ie, does it have a name), or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`33` and `93` are used for normalizing values beween `!` and `~`.

[image]

```
var data = '!';
Math.min(1,(data.charCodeAt(0*2)-33)/93); // will yield 0
```

```
var data = '~';
Math.min(1,(data.charCodeAt(0*2)-33)/93); // will yield 1
```

```
var data = '"';
Math.min(1,(data.charCodeAt(0*2)-33)/93); // will yield 0.010752688172043012
```

```
var data = '#';
Math.min(1,(data.charCodeAt(0*2)-33)/93); // will yield 0.021505376344086023

// ... and so on
```

The `|0` is there due to the fact that `sampleIndex*2` or `sampleIndex*2+1` will yield a non-integer value when being passed a non-integer `sampleIndex`. `|0` truncates the decimal part just in case someone sends in an incorrectly formatted `sampleIndex` (i.e. non-integer).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the range of the characters in that file are from `!` to `~`. `!` has an ASCII code of 33 and `~` has an ASCII code of 126. 126-33 = 93.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bitwise OR with zero will truncate the number on the LHS to a integer. Not sure about the rest of your question though, sorry.

93 and 33 are ASCII codes (not unicode) for the characters "]" and "!" respectively. Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you forever:

http://www.asciitable.com/

ASCIII codes for everything.

Enjoy!